# Separate Sort by table heading for different tables

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In the following [codepen](https://codepen.io/centem/pen/MWYgvPL?editors=1010) I'm trying to sort by the column headers independently on two different tables. However, when I sort on any of the two tables it also sorts the columns of the other table. I tried creating a separate sort function called sortByB and using that on one of the tables but it still sorts the other table. Thank you.

JS

```
$scope.sortBy = function(sortField) {
  $scope.reverseOrder = ($scope.sortField === sortField) ? !$scope.reverseOrder : false;
  $scope.sortField = sortField;
};

$scope.sortByB = function(sortField) {
  $scope.reverseOrder = ($scope.sortField === sortField) ? !$scope.reverseOrder : false;
  $scope.sortField = sortField;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this code:

```
<tr ng-repeat="ticket in filteredTicketA | filter:var2 | filter:searchTextA:true:Status | orderBy:sortField:reverseOrder">
```

The `orderBy:sortField:reverseOrder` part controls the sorting.

Right now, `sortField` and `reverseOrder` are shared between your two tables. You would need two `sortField` and two `reverseOrder` variables if you want different sorting settings for the two different tables.

Also note that you may not need to duplicate the data array, nor the sort callback.

Comment: Thank you Geo. That did it.